# How to insert new 2-level columns as mean of other 2-level columns in multiindex dataframe with Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas DF:

```
        bar                 baz        
        one       two       one       two

aaa       1         2         3         4
bbb       1         2         3         4
```

I would like to have a new column `mean` per all 1-level group with the mean value of respective exact (not all) 2-level columns (`one`, `two`). So the expected result:

```
        bar                           baz          
        one       two       mean      one       two     mean

aaa       1         2        1.5        3         4      3.5
bbb       1         2        1.5        3         4      3.5
```

What is the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply aggregates, specifying the axis, see example below for one method:

```
# Add the appropriate multi index name
df[('bar','bar_mean')] = df['bar'].mean(axis=1)
```

[image: snippet-of-bar_mean-added-to-df]

```
# Sort dataframe by index level
df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

[image: sorted-df-with-bar_mean]